# Dynamically populate value of array in a Div

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm creating an function that can shuffle and deal poker deck to user based on number of player provided by the user in a input field. I've completed the shuffling function but I'm having issue with dealing the card. How can I deal the entire deck equally based on the `number_of_people` value given in html, for example if the `number_of_people = 3` :

```
Person 1 : S-Q, D-J, D-K, C-7, S-J....
Person 2 : H-6, D-X, D-A, H-2, S-6....
Person 3 : D-Q, H-5, D-8, S-2, S-8....
```

also if user insert more than 52 `number_of_people` it will still deal and display but the 53rd and above player will have an empty hand e.g :

```
Person 53 : 
Person 54 : 
Person 55 :
```

Below is my code :

HTML :

```
    <div class="position-ref full-height">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Let's Play
            </div>

            <div>
                <input id="number_of_people" type="number" max="99" placeholder="No. of People"></input>
                <button onclick="shuffleCards()">Shuffle</button>
            </div>

            <div class="results">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript :

```
    // Create a function to distribute card
    function shuffleCards() {
        // Get input value
        var number_of_people = document.getElementById("number_of_people").value

        // Declare card elements
        const card_types = ["S", "D", "C", "H"];
        const card_values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "X", "J", "Q", "K",];

        // Create deck array
        let deck = [];
        
        // Validate the value inserted by user
        if (number_of_people > 0 && number_of_people !== null) {
            // Create a deck of cards
            for (let i = 0; i < card_types.length; i++) {
                for (let x = 0; x < card_values.length; x++) {
                    let card = { cardValue: card_values[x], cardTypes: card_types[i] };
                    deck.push(card);
                }
            }

            // Shuffle the cards
            for (let i = deck.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
                let temp = deck[i];
                deck[i] = deck[j];
                deck[j] = temp;
            }

            // Clear content
            $(".results").html(``);

            // Distribute the card
            for (let i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
                console.log(`${deck[i].cardTypes}-${deck[i].cardValue}`)
                $(".results").append( `<p>${deck[i].cardTypes}-${deck[i].cardValue}, </p>` );
            }
        }

        else {
            $(".results").html( `<h3>Input value does not exist or value is invalid</h3>` );
            return;
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the "Distribute the cards" loop, with the following loop:

```
for (let person = 0; person < number_of_people; person++) {
    $(".results").append(
        $("<p>").append(
            `Person ${person+1}: `,
            deck.splice(-Math.ceil(deck.length / (number_of_people - person))).map(card =>
                `${card.cardTypes}-${card.cardValue}`
            ).join(", ")
        )
    );
}
```

This actually extracts the right amount of cards from the end of the deck in one go, and displays them on a single line. Since the deck of cards is shuffled, it doesn't matter from where in the deck you pull the cards, so you might as well do it like this.

A remark about your code:

```
if (number_of_people > 0 && number_of_people !== null) {
```

If the first of these two conditions is true, then the second is always true as well, so there is no need to have that second condition. Moreover, the `.value` property of an input element is never `null`, but potentially an empty string.

You should really convert the input from string to a number. For instance with the unary plus:

```
var number_of_people = +document.getElementById("number_of_people").value;
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, much appreciated with the advice. this is my first time encounter with Math.ceil. will look into it as well